# Touch is not defined - FIREFOX?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите плиз, учебная задача, имитировать передвижение ползунка мышью. 
Есть код который работает в Chrome, но не работает в Firefox.
Как его можно адаптировать под Firefox?
В FF ошибка `ReferenceError: Touch is not defined`.
Пример ползунка можно найти на входной странице [Aliexpress](https://login.aliexpress.ru/?spm=2114.best.1000002.7.4375ruW1ruW19q&return=https%3A%2F%2Fbest.aliexpress.ru%2F%3Flan%3Den&from=lighthouse&random=8D3B5092C2AD210AF7EA9300479FB2AC) если несколько раз ввести не правильные данные для входа.

заранее спасибо за любые подсказки, мысли.

Скрин ползунка 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот код работает в Chrome

```js
/* eventType is 'touchstart', 'touchmove', 'touchend'... */
function sendTouchEvent(x, y, element, eventType) {
  const touchObj = new Touch({
    identifier: Date.now(),
    target: element,
    clientX: x,
    clientY: y,
    radiusX: 2.5,
    radiusY: 2.5,
    rotationAngle: 10,
    force: 0.5,
  });

  const touchEvent = new TouchEvent(eventType, {
    cancelable: true,
    bubbles: true,
    touches: [touchObj],
    targetTouches: [],
    changedTouches: [touchObj],
    shiftKey: true,
  });

  element.dispatchEvent(touchEvent);
}

const myElement = document.getElementById('nc_1_n1z')

sendTouchEvent(150, 150, myElement, 'touchstart');
sendTouchEvent(500, 500, myElement, 'touchmove');
sendTouchEvent(220, 200, myElement, 'touchend');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы не навешивать событием на элемент?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/target

`event instanceof MouseEvent && event instanceof window.PointerEvent &&  !!window.PointerEvent`

ну и надо проверочку делать на существование тача